# How can I determine my user account's OU in a Windows domain?

Tags: windows, active-directory

Is there any way (short of getting an active directory browser) to view my OU while logged in to the domain?

Comment: Are you a domain admin, or have access to the domain admin tools?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**UPDATE**
You should now use [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/883533/1054) on any kind of modern version of Windows

---

Here's a quick VBS script you can use to display your account's DistinguishedName attribute which contains the OU that your account is in:

```
set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & objSysInfo.UserName)
wscript.echo "DN: " & objUser.distinguishedName
```

**EDIT:** I should say that it will display the DN of the account in which context the script is run...

Comment: You beat me to it by about 15 seconds! Zow...

Comment: I beat him but for some reason gpresult /r doesn't work for everyone. "snaps fingers in lost pointage regret" ;-)

Comment: Aye, 'tis true :)  +1 though, great command!

Comment: Not sure why this is the accepted answer when "whoami /fqdn" is far simpler?

Answer (score 57):

gpresult /r | find "OU"

will do it.

Comment: Is this a windows command? Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: /r doesn't work for me, although you do get almost everything otherwise with gpresult.

Comment: When I do it there is a user setting section that shows the OU.

Comment: Awesome command that I didn't know about. Thanks! +1

Comment: /R  Displays RSoP summary data.

Comment: Luke, what version of windows? I'm on vista ultimate

Comment: I believe /R appeared in Vista/2008

Comment: Nice, I did not know about that command either.

Comment: Still works in Windows 10

Comment: Needs to be 'findstr' instead of 'find'

Answer (score 38):

In Command Prompt,

```
whoami /fqdn
```

Comment: Works in the event `gpresult` yields `ERROR: Access Denied`. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I've found that

```
gpresult -v|more
```

also works for this.

Answer (score 3):

I am able to run the following in a cmd window

```
gpresult /r | find "OU"
```

Example output:

```
USER SETTINGS
--------------
CN=Lastname\, Firstname,OU=Users,OU=Toronto,DC=site,DC=com

    Last time Group Policy was applied: 1/24/2019 at 4:04:04 PM
    Group Policy was applied from:      dc.site.com
    Group Policy slow link threshold:   500 kbps
    Domain Name:                        SITE
    Domain Type:                        Windows 2008 or later
```

It also lists the user groups you are a member of:

```
The user is a part of the following security groups
---------------------------------------------------
    Domain Users
    Everyone
    BUILTIN\Administrators
    BUILTIN\Users
    Performance Log Users
    NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE
    CONSOLE LOGON
    NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
    This Organization
    LOCAL
    custom_security_linux_group
```

Answer (score 2):

User: adfind -sc u:%username% dn

Computer: adfind -sc c:%computername% dn

Adfind available at http://www.joeware.net/freetools/tools/adfind/index.htm

Comment: adfind is one of my favorite AD tools. I <3 joeware.

Answer (score 2):

At a command / powershell prompt:

```
dsquery user -name <your-user-name>
```